# IntelliJ IDEA 11.1.2 does not copy SQL files to the out folder

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle

I am using IntelliJ IDEA 11.1.2 Ultimate with Gradle 1.0 multi module project. One module represents the domain. [image: module structure]

The projects output is points to *[project-root]\out.* But if I run a unit test the output folder of the domain module does not contain any .sql files at all. [image: Output folder of domain]. This is how I run the JUnit test within IntelliJ IDEA [image: Test configuration].

If I run the project using Gradle from command line everything works fine.

[image: IDEA project structure]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`Settings` | `Compiler` | `Resource Patterns`, add the pattern for the `sql` extension.